# User/register Page is not found in Drupal 6 site

Tags: users

The user login and user register page are not found in my drupal 6 site.It was working fine until before yesterday and I changed the user login page link as www.sitename/user instead of www.sitename/user/login but the register page is still not found.

Is there any way to get back the user/register page? I didnt installed any module recently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the clean URLs? There might be a problem with clean URLs.

Try www.sitename/?q=user/login.

Comment: Yes mohit_rocks. I checked the clean urls its already enabled.

Comment: cleared cache and rebuild menu router..you can get using devel module

Comment: how to rebuild menu router by using devel module?Can you please explain this mohit_rocks?

Comment: clearing menu cache will do it

Comment: ok Will try this.

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506812/page-not-found-error-in-drupal

Comment: Tried these 3 steps 
   1. Rebuild the menues by loading admin/build/modules
   2. Clear the cache via admin/settings/performance
   3. Rebuilt permissions admin/content/node-settings
 but didn't get register page. I put my site in offline mode.